# How to properly terminate cv2.VideoCapture when reading from a file?

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote some code to read in a video and write out each frame as an image into a directory.  The code performs the intended function but only terminates about 40 seconds after the last frame was written. [python 2.7; cv2 version 2.4.8]

```
import cv2
import os

def video_to_frames(video, path_output_dir):
    # extract frames from a video and save to directory as 'x.png' where 
    # x is the frame index
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
    count = 0
    while vidcap.isOpened():
        success, image = vidcap.read()
        if success:
            cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path_output_dir, '%d.png') % count, image)
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    vidcap.release()

video_to_frames('../somepath/myvid.mp4', '../somepath/out')
```

The output is correct, but I find myself manually killing the process rather than wait for vidcap.read() to return False.
Is there a faster way to exit from the VideoCapture.isOpened() loop?

Comment: That's the structure I use, does it do that with all videos?

Comment: I just tried this with some other videos and they all terminate immediately after writing the last frame.  Any idea why a particular video would get hung up? Also, what should I do with this question now since there would appear to be nothing wrong with the code?

Comment: If you don't think it'll ever serve to help future viewers, you could delete it, but given that you've figured it out may be video-specific, I may lave it just for that.  As for your video, you could read the frames using this structure then re-write them to a different file with a [`VideoWriter`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter).  The resulting file may process faster.  Alternatively, you could read the frames once then [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) the frames -- that's something I've done

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I've taken the offending video's frames and written them with VideoWriter in a few different fourcc formats (XVID, DIVX, iYUV), with no particular reasoning why I chose these.  I then unpack these videos into frames using the same code above.  There is some lag between the last frame written and the program terminating, but it's about 20 seconds now.  Anyway, I will leave this question up.  Thanks for the help.